# Is .GetAwaiter().GetResult(); safe for general use?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I read in a few places that `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` could cause deadlocks and that we should use `async`/`await` instead. But I see many code samples where this is used. Is it ok to use it? Which are the cases where it can deadlock? Is there something else I should use, like `Task.Wait`?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As I describe on my blog, [`GetAwaiter().GetResult()` can deadlock when it's used in a one-thread-at-a-time context](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). This is most commonly seen when called on the UI thread or in an ASP.NET context (for pre-Core ASP.NET).

`Wait` has the same problems. The appropriate fix is to use `await`, and make the calling code asynchronous.

Note that the `Main` method in Console apps is an exception to this rule; it is perfectly appropriate to use there. Many code samples use it in this way.

Comment: I think this is also true for WebApi services, correct?

Comment: @Cyan: Yes, any kind of ASP.NET request context. Pre-Core, that is; the request context was removed in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: "Main method in Console apps is an exception to this rule; it is perfectly appropriate to use there. Many code samples use it in this way." has a perfect point here. Thanks!

Comment: @stephenCleary would the comment about main methods apply to methods fired from within a thread started from ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?

Comment: @Martin: You want to block the main thread in a Console app because otherwise the application exits. Why would you want to block a thread pool thread?

Comment: @StephenCleary best answer is "reasons", we fire off a thread per "thing", and that shares some code that Async as used in a web solution... would prefer not to recreate the code as Sync if I can help it...

Comment: @Martin: I assume you mean that you're using thread-local state or some other mechanism that requires a dedicated thread, and that you don't want to make the code *asynchronous*. In that case, sure, just use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. I'm assuming your dedicated thread is contextless, so it shouldn't deadlock.

Comment: @StephenCleary, what about Azure Functions? .Net Core is only in preview if you select the beta runtime version in App Settings. Is that the better option?

Comment: @BrewMate: Azure Functions always runs your code without a context, both in ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET Classic.

Comment: @StephenCleary , in your opinion, is there an way to run a async method sync safely?  Thanks.

Comment: @Steven.Xi: Not in the general case. In specific scenarios, it can be done. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx

Answer (score 2):

When considering these kinds of things, it always helps to look at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.configuredtaskawaitable.configuredtaskawaiter.getresult?view=net-7.0#system-runtime-compilerservices-configuredtaskawaitable-configuredtaskawaiter-getresult). In the remarks section you will find this:

> This method is intended for compiler use; do not use it directly in
> your code.

I think that gives a fairly strong steer on this. It basically gives the developers of .Net a licence to change how it works in the future. They may never do so, but I wouldn't be confident myself. As for what else you should be using it would depend upon the context, but async/await is the most likely alternative.