# How to call an async method?

Tags: c#

I am not familiar with threading in .NET.

I have an ansync method MyTest:

```
public async Task MyTest() {
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_uri);

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("API/GetData");

        if(response!=null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I am running into is calling the method to get the results (Dictionary).

When I step though my code I am seeing the IsCompleted is done before the results come back from my rest call.

How do I properly use threading in this case?

My method to call the async method.

```
public void GetTestData()
{
    try
    {                
        ARestService rest = new ARestService();
        Task tsk = new Task(rest.MyTest);
        if (tsk.IsCompleted)
        {
            var tst = "Done?";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string a = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, feel free to read some tutorials on async/await instead of fumbling your way through the dark.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: Just call it and await the result. Or await it directly. The method is asynchronous because **.ReadAsStringAsync** is already asynchronous and runs in the background. The method returns an already running task that you just have to await

Comment: What you want is to `await` it if you want it to be asynchronous (the thread is not blocked while waiting on IO) or you can call `Result` or `Wait` on the task to synchronously block the thread.

Comment: *NOT a duplicate*, that question is about `async void`, a very special case.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I think the 2nd answer still applies though (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25097498/1260204).

Answer (score -1):

If you can turn your `GetTestData` method into an `async` method simply do this.

```
public async Task GetTestData()
{
    try
    {                
        ARestService rest = new ARestService();
        await rest.MyTest();
        var tst = "Done?";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string a = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

You should also define that your method returns a `Task<Dictionary<string, string>>` to receive the result of your rest service call, with the following statement.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = await rest.MyTest();
```

If not, have a look at some workarounds, like using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` but as explained in this question [Is .GetAwaiter().GetResult(); safe for general use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007006/is-getawaiter-getresult-safe-for-general-use) it can cause some problems, so the best option is to make your calling code async too.

Comment: First, you are hiding possible exepctions. Second, the other question is about `async void` *only*. You can just call `.Result` on the return value if you want to block synchronously

Comment: Good point! I realized the link is not exactly the same scenario. I have seldom used the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` workaround only in console applications.