# Web request from HttpClient stuck

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, .net-core, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I created http request with HttpClient class.I want to make GET request to some url. For example "http://www.google.com", or another url.

My application hosted in Amazon EC2 and use .Net Core 2.2.

```
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    private static async Task HttpClientRequestAsync(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(responseJson);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I don't know why, but my request stuck in client.GetAsync. After that nothing happens, without any response or exceptions. It is very strangely, because I can see this behavior only on Amazon EC2 instance. In my local machine this request successfully run. When I use Postman or Chrome on EC2 machine and create the same request - I receive response. If i replace HttpClient to WebRequest - I have the same behavior.

Thank you in advance

Minimal reproducible example for Console App:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClientRequestAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    private static async Task HttpClientRequestAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your url:");
            var url = Console.ReadLine();

            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(responseJson);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any URLs. I have the same behavior

Comment: maybe because you have 2 awaits in there?

Comment: `HttpClientRequestAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is your problem, this will be deadlocking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is .GetAwaiter().GetResult(); safe for general use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007006/is-getawaiter-getresult-safe-for-general-use)

Comment: @BugFinder my code don't  reach second await in this scenario

Comment: GetAwaiter().GetResult() it is only example for console application @Liam

Comment: I can replace HttpClient to WebRequest and behawior will be the same

Comment: Then we need a proper [mcve] then @Dev123

Comment: Note you could use [async Task Main](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/) for your example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disabling proxy when i created HttpClient helped me:
UseProxy = false;
Proxy = null;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
HttpClientRequestAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

use this:

```
Task.Run(async () => await HttpClientRequestAsync());
```