# Neither GetAwaiter().GetResult() nor .Result worked for me but Task.Run(await ()=> nameOfMethodTobeCalled()).Result working. I didn't understand?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, async-await, task-parallel-library

In my asp.net application I was calling some async method of one my nuget package I added into my application. Now I have a sync method in which I need to call async method of .dll I added. So for that I called those method and to retrieve result I used 
    var value = myDllClient.MyMethod().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); and 
    var value = myDllClient.MyMethod().Result;,  
 
But none of these worked for me but the thread went into never ending process. I never received anything 
So I used 
 
    var value = Task.Run(async ()=> await myDllClient.MyMethod()).Result;
 
 is surprisingly working fine.
I don't know how is it working?
Can anyone help me to understand this mystery?  
 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not working - you mean just stuck on `.GetResult()` or `.Result` line and not executing further?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007006/is-getawaiter-getresult-safe-for-general-use

Comment: I never received anything from lost call at .GetRestul()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So for that I called those method and to retrieve result I used

A better solution is to use `await` and [allow the asynchrony to grow naturally through the code base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). If you do **have** to do sync-over-async, then [direct blocking like that may cause deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

[`await` captures a context by default](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), and in your case the `await` inside of `MyMethod` is capturing an [ASP.NET request context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net), which existed on [pre-Core](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) versions of ASP.NET. Then, the calling code blocks a thread in that request context by calling `GetResult()`/`Result`. Later, when the `await` is ready to continue, it schedules the remainder of `MyMethod` to that context. But it will never be run because there's a thread blocked in that context waiting for `MyMethod` to complete.

The reason `Task.Run` doesn't deadlock is because `MyMethod` uses the thread pool context instead of an ASP.NET request context. This is the ["thread pool hack"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development) approach to doing sync-over-async. However, [`Task.Run` is not recommended on ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net); if possible, change the code to use `await` instead.

Comment: Changing code all the way async is not possible as I working on a very old service of microsoft build on asp.net. Now I was required to implement one of their new dll. 
If Task.Run is not preferred then what Should I use as I can't convert it all await? 
Thanks your above wonderful guidance @Stephen Cleary..

Comment: @MukeemAhmed: In that case, I would use something like [this `NoContext` method](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/e637035c775f99b50c458d4a90e330563ecfd07b/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/SynchronizationContextSwitcher.cs#L36-L54)

Answer (score 4):

By wrapping your call in `Task.Run` you are isolating that code from ASP.NET's `SynchronizationContext` and thus your code doesn't deadlock.